# R + snow + cluster: Kill slaves when master dies

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, kill, snow

I am parallelizing my R code with snow using clusters (SOCK type) in an Ubuntu 16 LTS. A simpler code example is below:

```
# Make cluster of type SOCK
cl <- makeCluster(hostsList, type = "SOCK")
clusterExport(cl, "task");

# Compute long time tasks
result <- clusterApplyLB(cl, 1:50, function(x) task(x))

# Stop cluster
stopCluster(cl)
```

Task function can take a long time (minutes or hours), but when for some reasons in my application there is no need to continue computing the tasks, application is not able to stop all slaves processes. 
I can kill master R process but R slave processes remain until they finish (i.e. remain using CPU during several time).

I can not kill slave processes because their parent process is the system one (PPID = 1) so I don't know which slaves are related to master process I want to stop. I also tried to use a kind of interrupt to let master R process execute `stopCluster` function without succeed.

After a depth search, I did not found a solution for this. So, does anybody know a way to stop/kill the slaves or has an idea to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `hostsList` specify remote hosts? In that case, the workers will be started via ssh, and killing them will require ssh as well.

Comment: Yes, they are remote hosts in a same LAN, hence communication is done using SSH. I only found a workaround specifying manually a port in `makeCluster` and then, when needed, kill all R process in all hosts related to that port.